Bal extension (Wix Burn Toolkit) not found in Visual Studio 2022
Visual Studio 2022 wix project compiles a Wix bundle with the WixStandardBootstrapperApplication with an error:

Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error WIX0200 The BootstrapperApplication element contains an
unhandled extension element 'WixStandardBootstrapperApplication'.
Please ensure that the extension for elements in the
'http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal' namespace has been
provided. HippotizerV5Installer   C:\Users\pc\Documents\gh\git\HippoR6\Installer\Wix\MsiPackage.wxs   25

Do I need to do any extra steps to install the extension? i already have WixToolset.Bal.wixext and WixToolset.Bootstrapper.Native.Core nuget packages installed

Installation steps:
In Developer Powershell for 2022:
dotnet tool install --global wix --version 4.0.5


You can invoke the tool using the following command: wix Tool 'wix'
(version '4.0.5') was successfully installed.

wix --version


4.0.5+b9b2f1b4

Building wix4 project within Visual Studio 2022 works absolutely fine for  using wix scehmas:
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:netfx="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/netfx"
     xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui">

I can see the .msi, install and uninstall fine.
Now I switch to using a Bundle.
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:netfx="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/netfx"
     xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui"
     xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">

    <Bundle
        Name="testapp"
        Version="1.0.0"
        UpgradeCode="01234567-89AB-CDEF-0123-456789ABCDEF"
        Compressed="no"
        SplashScreenSourceFile="placeholder.jpg">

        <BootstrapperApplication>
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
                LicenseUrl=""
                Theme="hyperlinkLicense" />
        </BootstrapperApplication>
        
        <Chain>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="ThirdPartyInstallers" />
        </Chain>
        
    </Bundle>

    <Fragment>
        <PackageGroup Id="ThirdPartyInstallers">

            <!-- Microsoft Sync Framework -->
            <MsiPackage Id="Synchronisation" SourceFile="Synchronization.msi" />
            <MsiPackage Id="ProviderServices" SourceFile="ProviderServices.msi" />

            <!-- Npcap packet inspection library -->
            <ExePackage
                Compressed="no"
                DetectCondition="WixBundleInstalled=1"
                Permanent="no"
                InstallCondition="WixBundleInstalled=0"
                UninstallArguments=""
                Vital="yes"
                SourceFile="npcap-0.96.exe" />

        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>

</Wix>

I am now faced with the final error:

Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error WIX0200 The BootstrapperApplication element contains an
unhandled extension element 'WixStandardBootstrapperApplication'.
Please ensure that the extension for elements in the
'http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal' namespace has been
provided. HippotizerV5Installer   C:\Users\pc\Documents\gh\git\HippoR6\Installer\Wix\MsiPackage.wxs   25

I have installed Wix Heat via here: https://www.firegiant.com/wix/heatwave/
I also cannot see Burn in the projects "Wix Extension" group.

HEre is my Nuget Package Managers installed WixToolset for the solution:


Edit: I have updated the Visual Studio wix project to include the nuget packages:
<ItemGroup>    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Heat"
Version="4.0.5" />    <PackageReference
Include="WixToolset.Netfx.wixext" Version="4.0.5" />   
<PackageReference Include="WixToolset.UI.wixext" Version="4.0.5" />   
<PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Util.wixext" Version="4.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Bal.wixext" Version="4.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Bootstrapper.Native.Core"
Version="4.0.5" /> <PackageReference
Include="WixToolset.VisualStudio.wixext" Version="4.0.5" /> 
</ItemGroup>

The initial error is gone. Now it is replaced with failure to identify the intermediatary files:
The validation .wixpdb file: <.....> was not from a Windows Installer database build (.msi or .msm). Verify that the output type was actually an MSI Package or Merge Module.
3>Done building project ".wixproj" -- FAILED.
Edit 2: It seems this project was created using the wix4 (.msi) project template. This does not seem to be configurable in any of the .wxs files.
I suspect I will have to create a wix4 bundle project template then retry the test.
It seems I am rubber-ducking the internet, but I can leave this here to help others.
